# For every irreducible representation V of G, dimV $ \leq$ g/a.

Tags: representation-theory

For a finite group and an abelian subgroup A, A $\leq $G , |A|=a, |G|=g, then for every irreducible representation V of G, dimV $\leq $ g/a.
I think maybe I can use the equationn: $\sum n_{i}^{2}=|G|$ ,but I dont know how to use condition that A is abelian.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the following ingredients for the proof:

1. For every subgroup $H \subseteq G$ of $G$ and every irreducible representation $V$ of $G$ there exists an irreducible representation $V'$ of $H$ such that $V$ is a subrepresentation of the induced representation $Ind^G_H V'$ (Hint: Restrict $V$ to $H$ and take $V'$ an irreducible quotient of this restriction, then use Frobenius reciprocity.)
2. The dimension of any induced representation $Ind^G_H V'$ is $\frac{|G|}{|H|} \dim V'$.
3. The irreducible representations of finite abelian groups all have dimension $1$.